# solving for two points, having 4 defined, using linear graph as connector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been on it for few days now, maybe someone could tell me I am on the right track.

So i got 2 points of a linear graph:

```
Ax, Ay
Bx, By
```

And a `foo` number.

Also I got a statement :

```
foo = (Cx - Bx) / (Cy - By)
```

I need to find Cx, Cy

Now I have been trying to do it using linear graph equation. (y = mx + b)
Knowing `Ax, Ay, Bx, By`, I get `m` and `b` for the linear graph.

Ending up with:

```
foo = (Cx - Bx) / ( (m * Cx + b) - By)
```

Solving for `Cx`, i get :

```
Cx = (foo * (By - b) - Bx) / (foo * s - 1)
```

I have been reworking this one for a while now, but the results are not as expected.

--== START of EDIT ==--

With `Cx` equation I got above, I get `Cx = Bx`, or very close to it. (I run it on Python)

Expected result: `foo > Cx > Bx`

--== END if EDIT ==--

I wonder if this is a correct way of doing it and if I made some mistake. If so - maybe someone could point it out for me :)

Comment: It looks like you're assuming $(C_x,C_y)$ is a point on the given line through the two points $(A_x,A_y)$ and $(B_x,B_y)$. If that is assumed, you can't "solve for" both $C_x$ and $C_y$. All you can do is get an equation for $C_y$ in terms of $C_x$. To do that just equate slopes.

Comment: Hey, cheers for a reply. I see your point. What could be the method to find the closest point (Cx,Cy) to the line ?

Comment: @Katafalkas Use `$ C_x $` for $C_x$. Looks pretty that way. ^_^

Comment: @BackinaFlash huh? :) you lost me there :)

Comment: @Katafalkas : In your comment you ask about the closest point $(C_x,C_y)$ to the line, but isn't this point actually *on* the line? So this point is as close to the line as any point can be.